# how to get sql result length by java

Tags: java, sql, out-of-memory, resultset

I need to use thread exec Hive SQLs or MySQL SQLs.

But I don't know the sql result size. yesterday, some one exec a sql like

```sql
select column1 from table1 where id = 1
```

and the column1 return a 250M+ result, and it caused memory leaks.

So, is there any method to determine the size of an SQL result set before obtaining it.

Can I get the sql connection socket fd, and count the amount of data on this link?

Comment: You selected one column of one row and it contained a 250M+ result? More than 250 MB in a single field of a single record? That's insane. I don't think anyone would recommend doing that.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch This is written by our users. There may be logical problems with SQL, but we cannot rely on the user's development level to solve the problem.

Comment: Wait until your users do `select column1 from table1 where id = 1 -- drop table table1;`

Comment: call count(1) and check count before, but it is bad idea. Better write pagination for your data. Write data limit for your request and memory leak will not come. For example: get total count with count function, cut to many pieces with pagination

Answer (score 0):

Setting fetchSize alone might not be enough for the MySQL driver to start streaming the data from the DB instead of loading everything at once. You could try with

stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY); stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

There is another two more option

1. use row_number funtion and limit to read data in the chunks

var a = SELECT count(*) FROM table1
var i= a/100000

while i>0

SELECT Column1 from (
SELECT Column1, row_number() over(order by Column1) rwn FROM Table1 )T1 where rwn between i and 100000*i
i=i-1

option 2 store result into a temp table or in a csv file and use the temp table or csv file